# How to Replace multiple space in table column

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, replace

I have a table column and it have rows like:

```
Joe Loe
korea china
Dan  Ger
```

There are two space between Dan and Ger. I want replace this column values who include more than one space in my column, but how can I do this. please help me about this.

```
SELECT myTable.Columnx
FROM table myTable  
where REGEXP_LIKE(myTable.Columnx, '[[:space:]]*','')
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 5):

From regexp_like function i assume that you are using Oracle DB.

For replacing multiple spaces in your data you can use regexp_replace like below

```
select regexp_replace('Test          test', '([[:space:]]+)' , ' ') from dual
```

You can have as many as spaces you want, this function will replace it with just one space.

> ([[:space:]]+) means at least 1 or more spaces.